# .NET Core 2.1 returning ObjectResult with custom StatusCode

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am migrating from .NET Framework WebAPI to .NET Core 2.1 and I have an issue returning an ObjectResult() with a payload and a custom status code.
My endpoint looks something like this

```
public IActionResult Create([FromBody]string user) => _userService.CreateUser(user);
```

The user is a JSON object encoded in a base64 string, and I have a "raw request body" InputFormatter.

The method CreateUser() returns an ObjectResult which looks like this

```
public class InsertionOk : ObjectResult
    {
    public InsertionOk(object payload) : base(payload) {
    Value = payload;
    StatusCode = 1;
    ContentTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/plain"));
    }
```

This returns HTTP status code 504: Receive failure.
Fine then.
I then tried overriding async Task ExecuteResultAsync and CopyAsync to HttpContext.Response.Body using a StreamContent object.
This returned the right payload in the right format, but with status code 200. Not bad. So all I have to do is overwrite the status code... Except it returns another status code 504. Give me a shout if you know what's happening to my code or if you need extra details.

Comment: You wrote `StatusCode = 1` which is invalid. That aside your action could just specify a return type of string, which will automatically yield status code 200 and content type "text/plain".

Comment: Thank you for the reply. You're right, the StatusCode is a nullable type. I took the precaution of casting it to an int. Please treat the code above as pseudocode. Anyway, after pulling my hair out any further I am starting to believe it's a problem with Fiddler